# How do I Populate a DropDownList with Results from a Web Service Method?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have an ASP.NET 3.5 webforms application that needs to interact with an ASP.NET web service.  The web service provides a list of valid values to be populated into a dropdownlist.  Is it advisable to do this on the client side or the server side?  If done on the server side, how do I define a data source set to my asmx web service?  If done on the client side, please suggest a good JQuery widget.

Thanks much for your help!!

Comment: What data format is being returned?  xml/json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opts I'd define a WCF service that used one of the built in collection Data contracts to render a list in JSON:

```
[ServiceContract]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class optionsservice
{

    // Return a dynamic list of the options
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/getOptions?type={type}", Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormatJson)]
    public SelectOptions getOptions(string filter = "")
    {

        SelectOptions returnOptions = new SelectOptions();
        //get your datatable here. 
        foreach (DataRow r in tbl.Rows)
       {
          returnOptions.Add((string)r["id"], (string)r["value"]);
       }
       return returnOptions;

    }

    [CollectionDataContract(Name = "collection",
            KeyName = "id",
            ValueName = "value",
            Namespace = "")]
    public class SelectOptions : Dictionary<string, string> { }
}
```

You could also cast the datatable to a list but this was the only example code I had on-hand

Here is how you would load the box into jQuery:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      $(function(){
        $("select#ctlSelect").change(function(){
          $.getJSON("/select.php",{id: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
            var options = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
              options += '<option value="' + j[i].id + '">' + j[i]value + '</option>';
            }
             $("select#ctlSelect").html(options);
          })
        })
      })
      </script>
```